# Cant find Text Element in Headless Mode Selenium C#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, browser-automation

I am simply trying to get certain text in headless mode that I can get in windowed mode. In headless mode the string is just "" (Empty).

In windowed mode it works perfectly fine using the code below:

```
string actualStatusText = p_Util.Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("html/body/div[3]/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[4]")).Text;
//body > div.container.body-content > div > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(1) > td:nth-child(4)
//html/body/div[3]/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[4]
```

The comments show the two different ways I can get the text in windowed mode tested in Headless but doesn't work. (Tried both CSS and XPath)

Comment: Try using .getAttribute("innerText")

Comment: I had the same issue but no direct solution. We ended up asserting a value in a "data" attribute instead of the Text value directly. I didn't try Ryan Wilson's suggestion though.

Comment: @RyanWilson This worked! Thanks. Put it as an answer to help others

Comment: @Meta-Knight Ryans solution worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using .getAttribute("innerText") fixed the issue!

Thanks to @RyanWilson in the comments.

Comment: Glad that helped.